# Let $V$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vectorial space of finite dimension. Prove for all pair of vector ...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Good night. I was trying to solve this exercise but i'm stuck.

**Exercise:**

Let $V$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vectorial space of finite dimension. Prove for all pair of vector $u,v \in V$ such that $u\neq v$, exists a linear form $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $f(u)\neq f(v)$

**My work:**

> Suppose for all linear form $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ we have $f(u)=f(v)$.
>
> Then, $f(u)-f(v)=0$. That implies, $f(u-v)=0$
>   
> In consequence $u-v=0$ and we have $u=v$ for all $u,v\in V$
>   
> This is a contradiction that comes from supposing all linear form $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ we have $f(u)=f(v)$.
>
> In consequence, exists a linear form $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $f(u)\neq f(v)$

But i think my proof is bad. Can someone review and give a hint? 
I will be very grateful. Thanks for all!

Comment: Hint: think first if both $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, what linear form could you construct that would not satisfy $f(u) = f(v)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can extend the linear function defined on $Vect(u-v)$ by $f(u-v)=1$ to $V$.

Comment: Okay, but is a good way try to prove by contradiction? (with your hint)